# Get (overloaded) array values set using __set as class properties when returning the object

Tags: php

I has an attributes array in the model. I am setting it's values using `__set` and have `__get` implemented to return values from it. Like so:

```
protected $attributes = [];

public function __set($key, $val){
 $this->attributes[$key] = $val;
}

public function __get($key){
 return $this->attributes[$key] ?? throw new Exception("attribute not found");
}
```

Now when I do this:

```
$object = new Model;
$object->name = "Model name";
$object->some_other_prop = "some other prop";
return ["data" => $object];
```

I want the result to be:

```
"data" : {
  "name" : "Model name",
  "some_other_prop" : "Some other prop",
}
```

I have tried `__toString` method, by returning a json_encoded attributes array, but when assigned to data, it returns an empty object.

This is the result I am getting:

```
"data" : {}
```

I am trying to learn implementing an active record style model, and I know this is possible in Laravel. I have gone through Laravel's code base and I could not figure out how they did this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to access `$object->attributes`, not `$object`, and `$object->attributes` will be protected, and thus not visible.

Comment: What does your `__toString()` implementation look like?